# SQL Server 2012 - Full Text Search [Break word - Underscore]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

Let's say I want to search for a list containing 'PS3':

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE CONTAINS(Title, 'PS3')
```

When the Title is proceeded by an underscore it will not return it.

1. Oblivion-PS3 -> Good
2. Oblivion PS3 -> Good
3. Oblivion_PS3 -> Not returning

I suppose the underscore is not a break word.

How can I fix it so that the underscore can be used as a break word?

Comment: Do you want to implement custom work breaker ? This will help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shajan/archive/2005/12/09/extending-sql-2005-fulltext-search.aspx

Comment: I found it! :)

I changed the Language for Word Breaker in the Full-Text Catalog to Traditional Chinese.

I used the sys.dm_fts_parser in order to find what language could use the underscore as a break word.

1033 - English

1028 - Traditional Chinese

select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('Oblivion_PS3', 1028, 5, 0)
return Oblivion AND PS3

select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('Oblivion_PS3', 1033, 5, 0)
return Oblivion_PS3

Comment: Please post it as answer, so others can benefit. Good work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! :)

I changed the Language for Word Breaker in the Full-Text Catalog to Traditional Chinese.

I used the sys.dm_fts_parser in order to find what language could use the underscore as a break word.

1033 - English

1028 - Traditional Chinese

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('Oblivion_PS3', 1028, 5, 0)
```

return Oblivion AND PS3

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('Oblivion_PS3', 1033, 5, 0)
```

return Oblivion_PS3